# Feedbacks for Multiple Parts Can't Print using Cloze in Moodle

Tags: moodle, cloze

I am trying to create a 2 parts multiple choice questions. I want to give feedback for each part. But the obvious way of doing things doesn't work. See below. I am using the `cloze` function in `moodle`.

```
\begin{cloze}[feedback={This is a general feedback. This prints fine.}]{Problem}
\begin{multi}[vertical,feedback={Feedback for Part I can't print}]
Part I
\item* Choice 1
\item Choice 2
\end{multi}
\begin{multi}[vertical,feedback={Feedback for Part II can't print}]
Part II
\item* Choice 1
\item Choice 2
\end{multi}
\end{cloze}
```

As indicated, I can print only the general feedback BUT not the feedbacks for each part.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I reported something similar to @mbr in https://gitlab.mattgk.myds.me/mattguer/moodle/issues/73, trying to check now

Comment: That ping was mean to @mgk, sorry. The site seems be down at the moment.

Comment: feedbacks seems to work in the master, BTW

Comment: @Rmano so the short answer to my question is that "It is not doable at the moment" ?

Comment: @KevinL I fear the answer is: "the Moodle LMS will probably never support this. There is no point for the `moodle` LaTeX package to display information that will not make it to Moodle".

Comment: @KevinL If one of the two answers seems satisfying to you, could you please mark it as accepted? Otherwise, please take time to comment on what is left unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the [cloze syntax](https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Embedded_Answers_(Cloze)_question_type) of the Moodle LMS does not handle feedbacks at the level of embedded subquestions.

That is why, the `moodle` package just ignores the feedback keys set at this level.
In the documentation of the current development version of the package, this is kind of documented in Table 2: the key `feedback` is not mentioned as an option offered at the level of cloze subquestions.

[image: Table 2]
If you think the package should raise a warning or an error when this happens, you are welcome to fill an issue in the [gitlab repository](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/issues).

Comment: I had the impression it does work in the PDF, though. No idea if it works on Moodle itself, never used it...

Comment: I cannot remember a version of `moodle` where the feedbacks set at the level of cloze subquestions would have been shown in the PDF.

Comment: Hi Matthieu, see my answer above ;-) (if you can help with the warnings, that would be great)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I obtain with the latest (well, two days ago) version of `moodle.sty`

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{moodle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Quiz 1}

\begin{multi}[shuffle=true, points=1,feedback={First feedback}]{Quiz1/Test1}
    test one
    \item[feedback={wow!}]* 1
    \item[feedback={ach!}] 2
    \item 3
\end{multi}

\begin{cloze}[feedback={cloze feedback}]{Quiz1/Test3}
    This is a cloze question

    \begin{multi}[vertical]
        One sub
    \item[feedback={this no}] $\frac{1}{4} x^4+C$
    \item[feedback={this yes}]* $3x^2$
    \end{multi}

    \begin{multi}[vertical]
        Two sub
    \item* A
    \item B
    \end{multi}
\end{cloze}

\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

And I obtain: (the marks on the page are mine, obviously, not from the package):

[image]

I also get this warning that I am exploring

```
Package moodle Warning: Cloze Multi Shuffling only supported by Moodle 3.0+ on input line 31.

Package moodle Warning: Cloze Multi Shuffling only supported by Moodle 3.0+ on input line 31.

Overfull \hbox (6.79999pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 31--32
[][]

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 31--32
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. It is close to what I like but it would be great if we have a general feedback for each part within cloze.

Comment: Well, it seems that @mgk is right, that's not supported by the `cloze` protocol...

Comment: @Rmano you get warnings from the `moodle` package because the default is to shuffle the items offered for the students and this option was only offered in cloze multichoice starting from the Moodle LMS as of version 3.0.